# Performance monitoring of software releases

Tags: software-development

Is there any open-source software that will record and display performance metrics for software that is built using a CI server (e.g. Buildbot)?

Everything I can find is geared at monitoring the performance of websites. I want to measure the performance of a benchmark that is run during the CI build.

I'm thinking something like [this](https://perf.rust-lang.org/) or [this](https://arewefastyet.com/), but those appear to be custom solutions. Ideally it would support annotating the graph data points with their commits.

Comment: I have a similar query too :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally found one solution: [Codespeed](https://github.com/tobami/codespeed). It's a fairly simple Django server, originally created for comparing Python interpreter performance (see it in action [here](http://speed.pypy.org/)), but it works well for pretty much any benchmark.

The documentation is a *little* out of date, but Django is nice and simple so it's not too hard to set up.

Also it has the slightly odd concept of "Executables", which corresponds to the python interpreter used for the benchmark. My code is C++ so I have just interpreted this as the compiler, so I have "Clang -O3", "GCC -O0" and so on.

Result submission is via HTTP POST, which can be authenticated with HTTP Simple Auth (*it isn't by default currently so anyone can submit results*).

Comment: Please accept your own answer, in order to help others who read this in the future